# Switching from timescaledb to influxdb - How to organize data? (many datapoints, every query gets all data by given device id)

Tags: postgresql, time-series, influxdb, timescaledb

Currently I am using timescale db with one table (timestamp, device_id, group_id, data jsonb). I am considering switching to influxdb cause its scaling possibilities. Data size: about 10M rows.

Data schema:

1. Timestamp (obvious)
2. Device ID
3. Group ID
4. Data => from 2 up to 30 floating point values

All records grouped by Group ID are located under one Device ID. 99% of the time I need to get **all data points** by Device ID or Group ID with optional time boundary. There will be no need to query for a single measurement by given periodid. Retention - forever (deletion is only on demand).

Is influxdb a good choice for given requirements? If so, how to organize buckets/tags for such use case?

The fact that in most cases I do not need to query data partially and cross device is probably important.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be curious if you're having issue with TimescaleDB in some way or are maybe just unaware of some of it's capabilities.

Scaling at that level, and to [hundreds of millions or billions of rows](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/timescaledb-vs-influxdb-for-time-series-data-timescale-influx-sql-nosql-36489299877/) is easily achievable with TimescaleDB on a single instance. If you need horizontal scaling, TimescaleDB provides for that too through [distributed hypertables](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/distributed-hypertables). Also, multi-node scaling in InfluxDB is only available if you host with them, not in their current open source product.

If you need to retain data for a long period of time, [native compression](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression) is also a great feature to utilize and would allow you to retain data for a very long period of time (likely) and maybe even query historical data faster if it was ordered correctly in the compressed form.

Are there any specific issues/questions we can help with?

Comment: I am worried about database size. Storing values in dedicated columns can reduce db size by 30% in PG. My schema is flexible and in rare cases when I am going to need to query by some fields across the database, InfluxDB can be more efficient thus its build-in schema-free model (That is what I have read).